# SymbolicC`: Is there a CChar, i.e. a way to generate a single character constant?

Tags: code-generation

I am aware of CConstant and CString, but neither can output the single-char literal

```
'a'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
CArray[CString@"a", 0] // ToCCodeString
```

giving

```
"a"[0]
```

maybe wrap it in CParentheses.

Alternatively, just put it there verbatim (losing the type information):

```
CAssign[a, "'a'"] // ToCCodeString
```

gives

```
a = 'a'
```

Comment: Just put it there verbatim, there is really no need for the complication with `CArray`.  Generally, bits of C code can be written in a string. You only need symbolic representation when you want to manipulate it as an expression.